# SSRS #ParseError in deployment, not preview

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parse-error

I am currently using a placeholder field in a matrix to use different colored fonts within the same cell.

Here's a snippet of the expression code that populates the placeholder field (with HTML turned on):

```
iif(Sum(Fields!Claim_Count.Value)> 0,"<font color = 'Red' size = '4'>● </font>"&format(Sum(Fields!Claim_Count.Value), "#,0"),"<font color = 'green' size = '4'>● </font>"&format(Sum(Fields!Claim_Count.Value), "(#,0)"))
```

This works perfectly in the preview pane. However, when I deploy to the reporting server, the values come back as #ParseError.

The deployed report will work just fine if I remove the HTML flags. So that's the problem area. Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a browser error rather than from the Reporting server. Does size need a **pt**?

Have you tried using SPAN instead of FONT? I vaguely remember something about an issue I had using FONT that SPAN fixed for me.

```
<SPAN STYLE="font-size:6pt;color:GREEN;">My World</SPAN>
```